# FA Glyphicon Only Show As Squares

Tags: html, css, font-awesome, glyphicons

I have searched all over the internet searching for answers to why no matter what I do glyphicons just won't show up for me. They only show as a little square "[]".

I have made sure that I am linked to the correct path. and have all the files in my project like the other forum posts have said and I even tried to change the font-family like someone suggest but nothing changes.

Am I missing something? Can someone explain the fix to me in the simplest of terms? I am very new to HTML and CSS still and get confused quite easily!

```css
.main{
  overflow: auto;
  background: url(portal.png), black;
  max-width: 100%;
  min-height: 900px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.main-nav{
  text-align: right;
  margin: 50px 50px 0 0;
}

.main-nav li{
  display: inline;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 22px;
}

.main-nav li a{
  color: #A8F766;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.main-nav li a:hover{
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 2px #A8F766 solid;
}

.main-text h1{
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 150px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 70px;
}

.fa-bath{
  font-size: 90px;
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Practice</title>
    <link href="bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="main">
      <nav>
        <ul class="main-nav">
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>

      <div class="main-text">
        <h1>Placeholder.<i class="fa fa-gamepad"></i><br>Placeholder.<br>Placeholder.</h1>
      </div>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Link bootstrap.js
It can be downloaded from http://getbootstrap.com/

Answer (score 1):

This looks like path issue. Does all your `.css` files stored in single folder or different folders? If they are stored in different folders can you please list the folder structure for `.css` files?

Also, just wanted to point out an alternative approach using [BootstrapCDN](https://www.bootstrapcdn.com/fontawesome/) to directly link the css file.

For example, following worked for me:

```css
.fa-gamepad {
  color:blue;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>
   <h1>Game pad</h1>  
   <i class="fa fa-gamepad fa-5x"></i>
</body>
```

Comment: My folders look like so: Main Project Folder which contains bootstrap.css, styles.css, index.html, and my 2 images. Then I have the seperate CSS folder with all the font awesome files in it.

Comment: @CydoEntis If you are using linux file system, and if the folder name is `CSS` instead of `css` can you please update href="css/font-awesome.min.css"` to `href="CSS/font-awesome.min.css"` and check.